# htaccess [L] flag didn't work

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I have .htaccess file like this inside searchEngine folder inside htdocs of xampps

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^\/?test$ view/index.php [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$   http://google.com [NC,L]
```

then I type this in the address bar:

- localhost/searchEngine/test

Why this redirect to

- http://google.com

not

- view/index.php?

I thought this must be redirected to

- view/index.php

not

- http://google.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `mod_rewrite` runs in a loop. First rule is doing this:

Starting URL:

```
/searchEngine/test
```

Ending URL:

```
/searchEngine/view/index.php
```

Now `L` flag causes `mod_rewrite` to loop again. So now your starting URL becomes:

Starting URL:

```
/searchEngine/view/index.php
```

Now 1st rule' pattern `^test` doesn't match but your 2nd rule is using `.*` as matching pattern hence redirects to `google`.

You can have your rules as follows to prevent this behavior:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?test$ view/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^ http://google.com [R,L]
```

2nd rule has this additional condition:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
```

`REDIRECT_STATUS` is set to `200` after first rule's execution. So 2nd rule will redirect only if first rule hasn't executed first hence it will skip `/test`.

If you're using Apache 2.4+ then you can use `END` instead of `L` to end the execution:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?test$ view/index.php [NC,END]

RewriteRule ^ http://google.com [R,L]
```

Comment: what does L flag actually does. i read a document and it said that: "Last - stop processing rules". i thought stop processing mean stop the loop

Comment: It doesn't `break` the the loop but acts as `continue` for the loop, hence loop executes again from start.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of the internal redirection, You can use the END flag instead of L to stop this behaviour :

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^\/?test$ view/index.php [NC,END]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$   http://google.com [NC,L]
```

Comment: does END flag break the loop?

Comment: Yes, it terminates the rule processing immediatly.